# слово "в завершение"?

Tags: синтаксис

Дано предложение. 
"В завершение встречи мы успели поговорить о своих планах на будущее".

======

**Вопрос.** Чем является в этом предложении сочетание ***в завершение*** -- **существительным с предлогом** или **предлогом**?

Answer (score 1):

> слово “в завершение”?

Предлог. [См.](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/144444):

> **в заверше́ние**
>
> ```
> предл. с род.
> ```
>
> Соответствует по значению сл.: после чего-либо, под конец
>   чего-либо.

Comment: Все задания выполните?

Comment: С остальной частью задания, думаю, Людмила и сама справится.

Comment: Не только об этом задании вопрос, если понимаете.

Comment: Из названия темы можно  было понять (во всяком случае, именно так я понял), что затруднение у автора вопроса вызвало именно сочетание _"в завершение"._ В задании требовалось (думаю, подобные задания -- уровень примерно третьего—пятого класса средней школы) _"подчеркнуть все члены предложения, указать части речи"._ Из своей практики знаю, что не только ученики, но и не все учителя _"в завершение"_ отмечают в подобных заданиях, как предлог. Потому и счёл целесообразным дать ссылку на словарь Ефремовой.

Comment: «Не только об этом задании вопрос, если понимаете.» Увлечься темой и помочь — здорово и понятно. Но вроде бы условились не превращать сайт в одну большую подсказку (лучше сказать: шпору) для тех, кому затруднительно зайти в тот же словарь Ефремовой.

Comment: @shampar после правки slava1947, несколько изменяющей смысл вопроса, вопрос стал вполне конкретным и понятным - уже и не закрыть с причиной "непонятна суть вопроса" или "домашнее задание нужно выполнять самостоятельно". А где уславливались, если не секрет?

Comment: Статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»? Это здесь: http://rus.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions.

Comment: Почему и как удаляются некоторые вопросы? http://rus.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions